# Extract mail attachments and body from a .msg file

Tags: extract

I'm developing a plugin for a DMS under Ubuntu 10.04. There is the need to extract mail attachments and body from uploaded .msg files. For those who don't know .msg is a [MS Outlook file format](http://www.fileformat.info/format/outlookmsg/). On Windows we used a .msg extractor but on Ubuntu i googled for hours and still haven't found anything.
There is one serious issue here:
.msg is Microsoft technology and most .msg extractors use Outlook and .net to get those attachments and body.

Do you know any workaround to make things work on a Ubuntu machine?

Answer (score 1):

I think the following link will help you -

http://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=HOWTO%3a_Read_Microsoft_Outlook_.MSG_files_in_Linux

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if the `tnef` package fits your needs? I am not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for.

From the package description:

> TNEF is a program for unpacking MIME attachments of type "application/ms-tnef". This is
>   typcially a Microsoft only attachment.
>
> The TNEF program allows one to unpack the attachments which were
>   encapsulated into the TNEF attachment, thus alleviating the need to
>   use Microsoft Outlook to view the attachment.

Homepage: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tnef